# How to avoid image garbage collection in python classes?

Tags: python, image, class, garbage-collection, python-imaging-library

So I started learning Python about 2 weeks ago and I'm running into a little problem when it comes to the garbage collection of images.

Specifically I am trying to load images on to a toolbar that is read from an XML file. I am using the following relevant code:

-- run.py --

```
    sections['toolbar'] = Toolbar(sections)
```

-- toolbar.py --

```
class Toolbar:
    def __init__(self, sections):
        # Make relevant variables easily accessible
        root = sections['root']

        # Create style
        ttk.Style().configure("Toolbar.TFrame", relief="raised")

        # Read toolbar data from XML file     
        toolbar_data = XMLParse("c:/PyApp/Builder/ui/toolbar.xml")
        toolbar_data = toolbar_data.read()

        # Create toolbar frame
        toolbar = ttk.Frame(root, style="Toolbar.TFrame")     

        # Loop through tools
        num = 0
        tool_img = []
        tool_button = []

        toolbar_datax = sorted(toolbar_data)                
        for tool in toolbar_datax:
            # Get tool id
            tool_id = toolbar_data[tool]['id']

            # Fetching tool image
            tool_img.append(PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(toolbar_data[tool]['image'])))
            print(tool_img)

            # Creating tool button         
            tool_button.append(Button(toolbar, image=tool_img[num], relief=FLAT, command=lambda tool_id_ = tool_id : self.pressed(tool_id_)))

            # Add tool button to toolbar
            tool_button[num].pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
            num += 1

        # Ensure that images do not get garbage collected
        self.tool_img = tool_img

        # Add toolbar to root                
        toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)  

        # Make relevant variables accessible throughout class
        self.sections = sections
```

-- Results --

```
[<PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x000001ED9A517198>]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
(path)\run.py in <module>()
     36 # --- SHOW TOOLBAR ---
     37 
---> 38 sections['toolbar'] = Toolbar(sections)
     39 
     40 # --- FINISH TOOLBAR ---
(path)\toolbar.py in __init__(self, sections)
     40 
     41             # Creating tool button
---> 42             tool_button.append(Button(toolbar, image=tool_img[num], relief=FLAT, command=lambda tool_id_ = tool_id : self.pressed(tool_id_)))
     43 
     44             # Add tool button to toolbar
(path) in __init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
   2207             overrelief, state, width
   2208         """
-> 2209         Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
   2210 
   2211     def flash(self):
(path) in __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
   2137             del cnf[k]
   2138         self.tk.call(
-> 2139             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
   2140         for k, v in classes:
   2141             k.configure(self, v)
TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

As you can see, I print the tool_img list to check the result. The image still exists at that point.

Also, I have tried to avoid garbage collecting by adding self.tool_img = tool_img, but that did not work.

Furthermore, I have tried another solution where I created a new class (Images) from which I created an object in run.py. After that, I adjusted the toolbar class to add the images to the object first and then call them, but it had the same outcome.

I hope I gave all the necessary information and would appreciate any push in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, printing tool_img[num] instead, gives pyimage1 instead of the image object.

Comment: I have tried several different ways now, including importing a shared module with a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a completely new structure and use a shared.py that includes object references. Then I added the images to an object reference and it is working now.